# Debian - Apache - User - Which chown?

Tags: debian, permissions, apache-http-server

I'm using Debian Wheezy. I've installed apache, php, mysql, the works. It works properly but for permissions that I need to set.

so I have my sites in `/var/www/mysite`, and I'm struggling between the permissions I should leave for apache and for my normal user. I want apache to be able to create/access files and folders, and I also need my normal user to be able to update, edit, create files and folders.

I've tried these combinations:

`chown -R www-data:www-data mysite/` but that doesnt let my user do anything on the files

`chown -R www-data:user mysite/` somethings wrong too

`chown -R user:www-data mysite/` wrong too

Right now I have this setting:

`chown -R user:user mysite/` but then on stuff newly created by apache, my browser cant load these assets and the server returns an error 403

Would be glad for some help

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to do use your first option:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data mysite/
```

But then add your user to the www-data group

```
usermod -a -G www-data user
```

and then give the group control over the files

```
chmod 770 -R /var/www/mysite
```

Chmod 770 basically means both the user who owns the file (in this case www-data) can do read-write-execute and all users in the group assigned to the file (in this case www-data as well) can do read-write-execute.

Comment: Yes, I figured that chmod was the way to go. I'll try also your recommendation of adding a user to the group. Cheers